# Python Continue permutation from certain point

Tags: python, permutation

I currently have a code that generates all permutations of 8 hexadecimal characters.
Since this takes quite long, is there a way I can stop it for the night and continue from where I left?

My current code:

```
for i in itertools.product(hexes, repeat=8):

        output = (''.join(i))

        f = open('test.txt', 'a')
        f.write(output + "\n")
        f.close

        print(output)
```

Comment: You are opening the file afresh every time through the loop. That is very slow. If you open the file before the loop and close it after, you might not need to stop it for the night. Also, `f.close` doesn't do what you think it does. It should be `f.close()`.

Comment: To answer your actual question (how to pause and resume a python job) it would be helpful to know 1) what system your task is running on (local, on a MacBook or Windows laptop, maybe?) and 2) how you're running the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not run this on a Jupyter notebook online so it could go all night? Then just extract the output file when it's done or have it sent to you via e-mail.

Also, printing the output will slow down the iteration A LOT
And I don't understand why do you open the file for every iteration.
A more correct approach:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'wb')
for i in itertools.product(hexes, repeat=8):
    f.write((''.join(i)) + "\n")
f.close()
```

Comment: Open the file in append if you were working on it before this code snippet